# Excel thinks Combo Box is clicked when sheet is calculated in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a number of private subs in Sheet code that refer to `ComboBoxXX_Click`. If I run another macro in the same Sheet that has SheetX.Calculate anywhere in the macro (referring to the sheet that contains the ComboBox) in the VB Editor using the step-into function, when it comes to execute the .calculate line it jumps to the `ComboBoxXX_Click` Macro. This makes me think that Excel is thinking that the ComboBox is clicked when the sheet is recalculated.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different option instead of ComboBoxXX_Click

I suggest looking at the list of events that can be triggered on MSDN for that control.

try MouseDown

Comment: dont post links as answers because in the future they could 404

Answer (score 0):

If you could add more information and blocks of code to help us help you. Also have you stepped through your code to find out at what point it is calling the `ComboBoxXX_Click`?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCKkd.png)

Here is an example of what I mean. Once the step into hits the Sheet4.Calculate on the first macro it skips to the second one (ComboBox25_Click) and if I step into the second one, once it reaches the Sheet4.Calculate line it also skips to a random ComboBoxXX_Click Macro.